# How do I use html5bolierplate build script?

Tags: html, ant, compression

Okay, so.

1. I've installed Ant.
2. Downloaded the build script. Extracted to Ant installation location.

When I run the 'runbuildscript' a cmd interface opens for around a second, and stops.

If I navigate to the location of files through CMD, then do `ant minify` it doesn't work.

I then thought to place and extract the build script in the location of the files.

Upon doing so, an error came -

```
BUILD FAILED
E:\NamanyayG\wamp\www\namanyayg\build.xml:150: The following error occurred whil
e executing this line:
E:\NamanyayG\wamp\www\namanyayg\build.xml:416: E:\NamanyayG\wamp\www\${dir.source} does    not exist.
```

Please help me out, I'm thoroughly confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build script expects some external process (in this case you) to set `dir.source` property.

The most sure way to set it is to define it on ant command line, e.g.

```
ant -Ddir.source=/path/to/dir.source
```

Comment: Is it do be done only once, or each time ant runs? Thanks, btw.

Comment: @Namanyayg: I don't know the structure of the `build.xml` that you are trying to run.  If it is a well designed project you should be able to create `build.properties` file and define `dir.source` in that file.  In this case you don't have to specify it on command line.  On the other hand if you cannot define this property through properties file, then you will always have to pass it through command line.  In this case I recommend creating a simple batch script so you don't need to type it all the time.

Comment: I'm using the `html5boilerplate` script. There's a build.xml there.